# how to read from a large text file to an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I'm trying to read from a very large text file  with two columns, it's a web graph, something like this: (except it has 40 million rows).

1 2

1 3

2 1
...

so i wanted to read from the txt file to myArray[mysize][2], and i used the code:

```
ifstream file("web-graph.txt");
if(file.is_open())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < mysize; i++)
    {
        file >> myArray[i][0];          
        file >> myArray[i][1];
    }
}
```

the problem is that it takes a long time to read such a big file. so is there any other way to read from the file that doesn't take this much time?

Comment: On which operating system? With which compiler? How did you compile your code (with which optimization flags)? Did you consider using plain C with `<stdio.h>` (on some systems, it might be slightly faster). Is your code a lot slower than e.g. a `wc` (word count) utility?

Comment: Just a suggestion: unless your data has the need to be stored in highly contiguous block of memory (e.g. a memory pool), **avoid using an array**, and **use a vector instead**.

Comment: @jrd1 what exactly do you think the difference is? And, OP, do you need it all in memory at once? What's the possible range of those integers (I assume you're storing them as integers)?

Comment: @jrd1: I can't understand why you believe that using `std::vector` would be faster than a plain old array...

Comment: @jrd1 what does "highly contiguous" mean? It either is, like an array or vector, or isn't, like a deque.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I never said it would be faster than a vector. ;) It's just that using a vector will have a number of distinct advantages over using an array. But, as noted in my comment, that depends on the purpose of it.

Comment: IMO, you are doing it the fastest way possible, you could obtain a small improvement with `scanf()`, but it's unlikely...

Comment: FWIW, on my Linux desktop, `wc` on a 6.6Mbytes textual file takes 0.12 seconds (once the file is in file system cache), so I guess that on a 100Mbyte file it would take less than 2 seconds. So your program should take a few seconds, which is not a big deal. If you are doing that many times, consider using something more efficient for the overall problem (perhaps some database, like MariaDB or MongoDB)... Perhaps it could be worth to buy a bit more RAM.

Comment: How much time does it really take to you on your machine. I'm guessing it should run in less than a dozen of seconds. Is your own development time and effort (e.g. a full day of work) worth the gain????

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possibly, subject to profiling, but you won't like the answer.
If you make the file smaller it might be quicker to read. How? Save it as binary, rather than text. Be aware this will stop you being able to use the nice high level streaming operators.
You will have to use lower level things instead, which might give you even more speedup. 

It might be better if you ask yourself why you are reading the whole file into memory. Again, if you made the file binary you could `seek` to the specific lines you are after. 

 
If you are performing a calculation on the file, perhaps you can process it as you go, or in chunks.

Comment: Of course not, but it gives some alternatives to try. My main question is really why are we trying to read such a big file in one go. But that's a question, not an answer

Comment: But 40Mega rows is not that big on current machines.... See my experimental timings.... (probably a dozen of seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're definitely doing it the slow (but pretty) way. You have 2 options to be faster:

if( you have enough memory )
{
    **Read the entire file into memory and, and *then* parse the file**
}

else
{
   **Read large chunks of the file at a time into memory, and *then* parse the file**
}

Either way, the loading looks something like this...

```
std::ifstream is(filename);
is.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
auto length = is.tellg();

std::string buffer;

if(length > 0)
{
    buffer.resize(static_cast<std::string::size_type>(length));
    is.seekg(0);
    is.read(&buffer.front(), length);
}
```

And then you would put it in a stringstream...

```
std::stringstream ss(buffer);
```

and parse it, potentially exactly how you were doing it before...

```
for(int i = 0; i < mysize; i++)
{
    ss >> myArray[i][0];          
    ss >> myArray[i][1];
}
```

Comment: But `std::ifstream` is buffered, so the "else" case is the default anyway.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's an implementation detail. I can say from experience, at least on Windows, that whatever buffering it has is not good enough if you're going to do so many reads. I've, more than once, gotten orders of magnitude better performance explicitly reading large chunks than using `>>`

Comment: In that case, then you might want to add that it might be better that the "large chunks" are a multiple of the disks block-size (which can b hard to get on Windows, so using some "even" multiple of 2 (like 4k, 16k or maybe even 1 or 2 meg) should work).